# Hibernate transaction id logging

Tags: hibernate, spring, log4j

is it possible to log something like hibernate transaction id? Does a hibernate transaction have a ID? Basically I have to log every transaction it would be great if those had a id.

Hope someone can suggest me a solution :)

I'm using spring 3 mvc, hibernate, hypersonic database, log4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using Spring, I assume you also use a Spring transaction manager. You can set log level for `org.springframework.transaction` package to `INFO` or even `DEBUG` to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, but what class should I log to get the parameters what where added to database?

Right now I get only this:
[2011-09-17 12:49:40,268] DEBUG [http-8080-1] (AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106) - Adding transactional method 'update' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''

Comment: Also I have to provide the user with a transaction ID what would be the best way to do that?